# Getting problems after installing Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Now I have transformed the magneto 1.9 files to root.
When I am opening the browser to register my site, I am getting this problem:

```
Warning: include_once(Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/dailybuy.dk/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/php/includes:/usr/share/php') in /home/www/dailybuy.dk/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line 49![enter image description here][1]
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but, if anyone still gets this error, I figured it out, go to `downloader/` folder and rename `mage.php` to `Mage.php`.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the file (mage.php) with this file: https://github.com/t0ster/magento-on-dotcloud/blob/master/www/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php